# AT&T ARO debug tool for android - error with tcpdump/key.db

Tags: android, debugging

Have anyone faced with the following problem, while starting the data collation on [AT&T's ARO](http://developer.att.com/developer/legalAgreementPage.jsp?passedItemId=9700312), an error message is thrown which says:

```
Emulator error with tcpdump/key.db push.
```

The following [documentation](https://developer.att.com/home/develop/ARO/ARO_UserGuide_1_4.pdf) mentions that but no suggestion, for any solution.

```
Occurs if there is an error while transferring the collected 
trace files from the device or device emulator to the local 
system. 
This transfer is initiated by the AT&T ARO Data Analyzer
when the Stop Collector menu option is selected on the 
Data Collector Menu, and the Pull Trace
```

Note: that this problem doesn't always occur, but I couldn't state what causes this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am on the ARO Team at AT&T.  Sorry that you have been having intermittent issues.  I have never seen this issue, but I need a bit more information to help track it down.  What Version of he ARO Analyzer are you using?  What version of Java, and are you on a PC or a Mac (OS versions)?  How large is the emulator's virtual SD card?

It sounds like you are getting this when you attempt to start a trace. Is that correct? Or are you getting the issue when you STOP data collection and the trace is copied off the emulator back to the Computer?

I'll Run this past our developers in advance of your response in case they have ever seen this issue.

Doug
@dougsillars
developer.att.com/ARO

Comment: Yes you are right, I'm getting an error when I attempt to start a trace.I'm sure what java version is installed on the PC (I'll update you, but my guess that it is 1.7), but I can assure you that it has nothing to do with the emulator version or the SD size card (I've tried different combination).Note that this doesn't always occur.

Comment: My developers tell me that we take about 2MB of the SD card at start for the ARO binaries.  If the SD card is full, it throws the error you are seeing. Since it may only 50% of the time that the card does not have enough room, that may account for your error. I'd build a new emulator with a larger virtual SD card.

Comment: I've upgraded the SD card up to 1024MiB, and it hasn't solved the problem. note that it doesn't work on ARM and ATOM well